# Getting a compile error including rosgraph_msgs/Log

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, occupancy-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings,

I am trying to use rosgraph_msgs/Log to subscribe to rosout and when I include the header file I get the following compile error:

```
<command-line>:0:7: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:95:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘DEBUG’
     DEBUG = 1,
     ^~~~~
<command-line>:0:7: error: expected ‘}’ before numeric constant
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:95:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘DEBUG’
     DEBUG = 1,
     ^~~~~
<command-line>:0:7: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:95:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘DEBUG’
     DEBUG = 1,
     ^~~~~

In file included from ....
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:103:52: error: ‘ContainerAllocator’ was not declared in this scope
   typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::rosgraph_msgs::Log_<ContainerAllocator> > Ptr;
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:103:70: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::rosgraph_msgs::Log_<ContainerAllocator> > Ptr;
                                                                      ^
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:103:72: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::rosgraph_msgs::Log_<ContainerAllocator> > Ptr;
                                                                        ^
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:104:52: error: ‘ContainerAllocator’ was not declared in this scope
   typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::rosgraph_msgs::Log_<ContainerAllocator> const> ConstPtr;
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:104:70: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::rosgraph_msgs::Log_<ContainerAllocator> const> ConstPtr;
                                                                      ^
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:104:77: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::rosgraph_msgs::Log_<ContainerAllocator> const> ConstPtr;
                                                                             ^
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:110:45: error: ‘Log’ is not a member of ‘rosgraph_msgs’
 typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::rosgraph_msgs::Log > LogPtr;
                                             ^~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:110:45: note: suggested alternative: ‘Log_’
 typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::rosgraph_msgs::Log > LogPtr;
                                             ^~~
                                             Log_
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:110:45: error: ‘Log’ is not a member of ‘rosgraph_msgs’
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:110:45: note: suggested alternative: ‘Log_’
 typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::rosgraph_msgs::Log > LogPtr;
                                             ^~~
                                             Log_
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:110:49: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::rosgraph_msgs::Log > LogPtr;
                                                 ^
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:111:45: error: ‘Log’ is not a member of ‘rosgraph_msgs’
 typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::rosgraph_msgs::Log const> LogConstPtr;
                                             ^~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:111:45: note: suggested alternative: ‘Log_’
 typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::rosgraph_msgs::Log const> LogConstPtr;
                                             ^~~
                                             Log_
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:111:45: error: ‘Log’ is not a member of ‘rosgraph_msgs’
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:111:45: note: suggested alternative: ‘Log_’
 typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::rosgraph_msgs::Log const> LogConstPtr;
                                             ^~~
                                             Log_
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:111:54: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::rosgraph_msgs::Log const> LogConstPtr;
                                                      ^
/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:155:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
 } // namespace rosgraph_msgs
 ^
```

When I comment out #include <rosgraph_msgs/Log.h> I compile fine.
rosgraph_msgs is added to my catkin_package in cmake and in my package.xml.
Versions: 1.11.2-0bionic.20201017.050047

Is there a hidden header dependency? Or is there another way to effectively subscribe to rosout?
Code I am attempting to make:

```
LogSubcriber = handle.subscribe<rosgraph_msgs::Log>( "/rosout_agg", 1, &LogStreamer::OnLogReceived, this);
void OnLogReceived( const rosgraph_msgs::Log & logMessage ); 
void LogStreamer::OnLogReceived( const ::rosgraph_msgs::LogConstPtr & logMessage ) {
    //...
 }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374204/getting-a-compile-error-including-rosgraph_msgs/log/) by [Rhapsodus](https://answers.ros.org/users/33193/rhapsodus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2021-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You provide very little information (not even the platform / OS you're building this on), so this is just a guess.

The error you show has this:

> ```
> /opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h:95:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘DEBUG’
> ```

```
     DEBUG = 1,
```

`DEBUG` is not a macro in `/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h`, but a member of an `enum`.

From `/opt/ros/melodic/include/rosgraph_msgs/Log.h`:

```
  enum {
    DEBUG = 1,
    INFO = 2,
    WARN = 4,
    ERROR = 8,
    FATAL = 16,
  };
```

Would you perhaps happen to have `#define`d a `DEBUG` macro yourself? Or have you used `#define DEBUG <some_value>` yourself?

That could cause this problem as the symbols would clash.

The rest of the errors are not interesting at this point, as it's very likely they're caused by the compiler trying to make sense of the rest of the file, which it can't.

> Is there a hidden header dependency?

if that was the case, in code which is around 12 years old, we would have probably seen more reports about this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rhapsodus](https://answers.ros.org/users/33193/rhapsodus/) on 2021-03-17**:
First off, I appreciate the help and sorry for not posting the Melodic / Ubuntu version. You are spot on correct here. There was a less than obvious Debug flag being set in the CmakeLists file. Removing these allowed the conflict to resolve.

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -DDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -DDEBUG")
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-18**:
Hm. I would not have expected *those* defines to cause a problem. We compile many parts of ROS with Debug settings enabled, and I've not run into a conflict there.

Are you sure it was those?